# Linux Development SMTP Server

Tags: ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, smtp

Everyone, I am looking for a good SMTP server for my development machine. I am running Linux mint 10. I need a good SMTP email trap that will listen to the localhost port and intercept all email originating from Ruby on Rails applications I am developing on without relaying them out to the world. The app needs to allow me to open and view the emails so I can review the test emails that are being sent.

I ask because when I worked on Windows there were tons of little applications I could install which would listen on port 25 and gather all the email sent from my applications as I developed and tested them. These little apps would allow me to open the emails after receipt so that I could verify the content of the emails. I need something like that on Linux (Mint 10 to be exact).

Advanced Thanks

Comment: I thinks this belongs on serverfault

Comment: now if I was asking about deploying a production SMTP server then yes. But my question is for local development of applications and testing the email they send without going through a production SMTP server.

Comment: I ask because when I worked on Windows there were tons of little applications I could install which would listen on port 25 and gather all the email sent from my applications as I developed and tested them. These little apps would allow me to open the emails after receipt so that I could verify the content of the emails. I need something like that on Linux (Mint 10 to be exact).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for Ruby on Rails development there is a simple gem that can be installed via your gem manager called Mailtrap.

See
http://www.rubyinside.com/mailtrap-dummy-ruby-smtp-server-ideal-for-testing-actionmailer-629.html

```
[sudo] gem install mailtrap
```

Make sure to add the following to your environment file (development)

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :domain => "mydomain.net",
    :address => "localhost",
    :port => 2525,
  }
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:2525' }
```

Answer (score 1):

All SMTP servers for linux can queue your mail if you dont tell them how to send the data on. I use exim, all the files for this and sendmail are stored in text format, so are very readable. So, both should suit your needs (sendmail comes with every distro Im aware of)

Comment: Is there a tutorial for setting up sendmail specifically as a localhost email catch so one can test emails sent from applications being developed locally. I need to be able to actually open and read the emails after they have been caught locally?

Comment: Sendmail by default will take all emails and stick them in a queue which can be found in /var/spool/mqueue http://www.feep.net/sendmail/tutorial/ was an OK tutorial, although http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/ is also good.

Comment: Sweet, thank you very much for your help, I will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

MailCatcher is a good option if you want something running locally (especially if you already have ruby).  It presents caught mail via a web interface.  Very simple and easy to install.  You then just configure your app to talk smtp to a different host/port (like in the mailtrap answer)

http://mailcatcher.me/

Answer (score 1):

I may be late to the game, but [fakeSMTP](http://nilhcem.github.io/FakeSMTP/) is a really nice and easy to use, open-source and cross-platform tool.

Answer (score 0):

An SMTP server of your choice, with an entry in the virtusertable for *@* or so that delivers to a single account.

Answer (score 0):

qmail is quick and scalable, see http://www.qmail.org/top.html

Answer (score 0):

We use [mail_safe](https://github.com/myronmarston/mail_safe). It redirects outgoing email in development to whatever email address you have registered with git. Really easy solution.

Only applicable if you're developing in Ruby on Rails though.